# Select rows which a string starts with

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string `/path/to/project/subdirectory/` and need to find a row where `path` is `/path/to/project/`.

How can I find rows where my string starts with `path`?

It would be the opposite of:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE path LIKE "/path/to/%"
```

Because I have too many characters, not too few.

---

Both of these return zero rows:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE path LIKE "/path/to/project/subdirectory/%"
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE "/path/to/project/subdirectory/" LIKE (path+"%")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close with your second attempt, but MySQL uses `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings, not `+`.

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE "/path/to/project/subdirectory/" LIKE CONCAT(path, '%')
```

You can also use

```
WHERE LOCATE(path, "/path/to/project/subdirectory/") = 1
```

Comment: But when does MySQL want double and singe quotes for string literals? Here you have both versions; "/path/to/project/subdirectory/" and '%'.

Comment: MySQL allows either single or double quotes around any string literal. They just have to match. I usually use single quotes because they're consistent with ANSI SQL. But I pasted the filename from the question, and didn't bother editing it.